# Converting Json JObject to a derived class

Tags: c#, json, reflection, json.net

I have an abstract class named NProcess from which I will derive many different Process objects.

```
public abstract class NProcess
{   
    public ProcessConfigurations ProcessSettings { get; set; } 
}
```

The ProcessessConfigutations class looks like :

```
[Browsable(true)]
public abstract class ProcessConfigurations { }
```

Examples  of objects to derive from NProcess are `EmailReader, FileCopier or FTPProcess`,.... can be anything and so the property classes derived from ProcessConfigurations will have a set of properties only related to the process.

I am able to load the processes derived from `Nprocess` using Reflection and when I select one a different set of properties appears in the property grid,as expected.

I am Serializing the settings and storing them in the database as BSON.

Problem :  Deserializing shows me the Json string but I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to
>   'ProcessConfigurations'

I need to be able to cast or convert the JObject to any **dynamic** Type derived from 'ProcessConfigurations' but I am unable to get the derived type.

Comment: Can you show how you are doing the conversion? If possible, also show the JSON object.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't have to scream;

Comment: I think you are looking for [deserialization](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm). Check out [JSON.NET deserialize to abstract class or interface](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/03/30/json-dotnet-deserialize-to-abstract-class-or-interface/) by Robert Muehsig if you need to deserialize to an abstract class.

Comment: show us some code please!

Comment: You don't want to convert the type.  You want to use the `ToObject<T>` method that exists on `JObject`.  `var result = jObjectVariable.ToObject<ProcessConfigurationsDerivedType>();` in combination with a concrete type derived from ProcessConfigurations.

Comment: dynamic Config = (GetConfig(Process.Id, Process));  // returns object
            
          //****  Problem area
            Process.ProcessSettings =(ProcessConfigurations) Config    . Note that the ProcessConfigurations base will become many objects I cannot anticipate at present. This means I cannot use one derived Type since that will make the behaviour less dynamic

Comment: @HanletEscano , here is the Json object: {
  "SourceFullPath": "c\\Source",
  "Destination": "c:\\temp",
  "OnExists": 1 
}      It can also be : {
  "ID": 222222,
  "Name": "Max soni  Alfred",
  "Latitude": 54233,
  "Longitude": 4545416
}

Comment: @MaxSoni - can you [edit] your question to give a complete [mcve] for your problem, starting from the JSON string (or file)?  One of your comments has a `GetConfig(Process.Id, Process)` but it's not clear what that doesn/

Comment: @dbc, `GetConfig(Process.Id,Process)` reads JSON from a database table where it is stored as a Base64String.After creating a JObject on the JSON data I need to convert it to any one of the subclasses/Derived classes of `ProcessConfigurations` the idea is to make the Configurations as dynamic as possible. One object derived from `ProcessConfigurations` can have ` { "SourceFullPath": "c\\Source", "Destination": "c:\\temp", "OnExists": 1 }` and another can have `{ "ID": 222222, "Name": "Max soni Alfred", "Latitude": 54233, "Longitude": 4545416 }`. Pardon me,its my first time here J.

Comment: The problem is probably the abstract type, i guess the compiler needs a concrete type to deserialise… The easiest would be to not mark the class abstract or to create a `ConcreteProcessConfigurations` class and deserialise in that type to retrieve the values.

Comment: (if your are using MongoDB, you will need to check the discriminator (_t) which will indicate in what derived type you are to deserialise)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each of the configurations are different classes, how will you know what type they should be when they come out of the database? Say you query the database and get back

```
{ "SourceFullPath": "c\\Source", "Destination": "c:\\temp", "OnExists": 1 }
```

You don't know to what concrete type it should be deserialized. And you can't just stuff it into a `ProcessConfigurations` class because `abstract` classes cannot be instantiated (the deserializer will conceptually need to "new up" an object and then copy the JSON properties into it).

So what can you do?

The immediate answer is to include the type information in the serialized Json. Json.Net has a feature where it will automatically do that for you. It's called [TypeNameHandling](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/serializetypenamehandling.htm). The resulting Json would look like:

```
{ "$type": "Your.Namespace.Here.MyConcreteProcessConfiguration, Your.Assembly.Here", "SourceFullPath": "c\\Source", "Destination": "c:\\temp", "OnExists": 1 }
```

Then when it's deserialized Json.Net will know which type to "new up".

If you don't want to use Json.Net's built in way to do this you'll have to store the type information in your own field and write a custom `JsonConverter` as mentioned in the link by @JDB: [JSON.NET deserialize to abstract class or interface](http://blog.codeinside.eu/2015/03/30/json-dotnet-deserialize-to-abstract-class-or-interface/). The `JsonConverter` would essentially do something like this to deserialize (taken from the above blog post):

```
public class MyConverter : JsonConverter {

    // ... other stuff, see the blog article

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);
        if (jo["MyCustomType"].Value<string>() == "MyConcreteProcessConfiguration")
            return jo.ToObject<MyConcreteProcessConfiguration>(serializer);

        if (jo["MyCustomType"].Value<string>() == "MyOtherConcreteProcessConfiguration")
            return jo.ToObject<MyOtherConcreteProcessConfiguration>(serializer);

       return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Following your post on using $type included in Json.net I was able to use `dynamic` as my type while Deserializing. This worked very well since the JObject knew which object to convert to.

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear it. Just as a reminder, don't forget to mark this answer as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer.